# Notification iOS 13+ and JavaPNS - Invalid token

Tags: ios, push-notification, javapns, ios13.7

I use JavaPNS (2.2) for send notification.
Now, with iOS 13.x, i have a problem.

This is my (new) code for register the device to server:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    
    NSString *tokenNotification = nil;
    NSUInteger length = deviceToken.length;
    if(length > 0) {
        const unsigned char *buffer = deviceToken.bytes;
        NSMutableString *hexString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(length * 2)];
        for(int i=0; i<length; ++i) {
            [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", buffer[i]];
        }
        
        tokenNotification = hexString;
    }

...
...
...

}
```

`tokenNotification` has same value of `deviceToken.debugDescription`.

When I try to send notification using JavaPNS, returns an error: "**Invalid token**".
I have this problem only on iOS 13+.
My device has iOS 13.7.
With iOS up to 12, using `deviceToken` as value of registration (without "<" and spaces), works fine.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved!
It was just a certificate issue. :)